# Total number of docs on a shard in solr

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, sharding, solrcloud

I am facing some issues when trying to understand how solr is generating score for a document on a shard.
When I query the shard using q=*:* params the numFound param returns 25151. Next I give a query and try to understand the score generated for a document in the response. There  I can see this log `2.3521233 = idf, computed as log((docCount+1)/(docFreq+1)) + 1 from:\n        278 = docFreq, number of documents containing term\n        25943 = docCount, total number of documents with field`. The url I am using to query a particular shard is

```
http://mySolrUrl/solr/myColleciton_shard24_replica_t46/select?q=*:*&distrib=false&wt=json
```

So I have 2 questions.

1. As per my understanding the docCount should be equal to the numFound param which is 25151 but it is not?
2. `log((25943+1)/(278+1)) + 1` is not equal to the calculated score. why is this?
   Any help here is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 1. If you haven't optimized your indexed, deleted documents will still count when scoring. They're not removed before the index gets rewritten by the merge policy or by an explicit optimize. For 2. it'd be helpful if you included the whole scoring output from when appending `debug=all`, and which similarity you're using (bm25 should be the default, and that formula doesn't match that one). There might be float encoding issues in play here depending on the chosen similarity.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh you were right about the deleted docs. Reg 2 I am still exploring. It could be some custom similarity implemented in my org.